# Why is there a groove line on the "F" and "J" keys on Apple keyboards?

Tags: keyboard

If you look at Apple's keyboards nowadays, you'll see that on the "F" and "J" keys there is a little groove line under the letter.

Why does this exist? What purpose does it serve?

[image]

Comment: It's a limited edition, marked with my initials. Please return all hardware that have them to me.

Comment: @JanFabry Absolutely love it!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually, this is a feature of all keyboards, and has been for as long as I can remember. Most keyboards use a line, but older Apple keyboards used a dot.

The goal of the ridge is to allow people who type without looking at the keyboard to easily find the right keys to put their fingers on. These keys are referred to as the [home row](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing#Home_row).

Both [Qwerty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qwerty) and [Dvorak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard) keyboards [(image)](http://www.micwil.com/images/gallery/matias_dvorak_keyboard_p1_1440x535.jpg) have these notches where you place you index fingers on the home row, which shows that the notches correspond to a location and not a particular letter.

**Bottom line: If you don't look at your keyboard, these are an important feature to let you put your hands where you need to. If you do look at your keyboard, these don't help you.**

Comment: Not to mention blind users.

Comment: Some of the older Apple keyboards had a more pronounced curvature of those keys. Many PC keyboards have lines on the D and K instead (for the middle fingers, instead of the index).

Comment: @NReilingh Really? I've never seen a board with D and K accented. As a curiosity, I'd love to see a photo of one like that if you can find one.

Comment: You'll see the same thing on telephones. The numeral '5' will have some sort of tactile cue on it. Same goes for ATM keypads as well.

Comment: @Nathan: http://www.old-computers.com/museum/photos/Apple_III_Keyboard_s1.jpg and http://bzupages.com/attachments/2304d1226874682-macplus_keyboard-jpg

Comment: @Aziz Interesting; I've never seen that before. Thanks for the links!

Comment: I love it when things have moved so far that few in a discussion know what "touch typing" is. Good call deceze on the accessibility piece of this. Makes me feel old that I learned to touch type on a manual typewriter (which also had the dots). Now, if we could figure out how to put those raised dots on an iPad keypad. ;)

Comment: As a user who types without looking on a decade old keyboard, I can tell exactly how annoying it is to have the notch erased by years of typing (I have this problem with <kbd>J</kbd>`). Always have to move my right index finger to the left one and count two keys to find the correct one. Otherwise, I get _gekki_ instead of _hello_.